# DbProviderFactory failed

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, database-connection

With C#, Framework 4.5 and MySqL connector installed on my PC

If I tried

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
...
MySqlConnection tst = new MySqlConnection();
```

Everything works, but now

> DbProviderFactory factory =
>   DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");

Raises the error :

**Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.**

Don't understand !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does your config file have an entry

```
  <system.data>
     <DbProviderFactories >
       <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with DbFactory for Firebird connections. The problem is, that it is not enough to add DbProviderFactories section to configuration file, but you must also add appropriate NuGet package to project, where you modified that config.